# Compile just a specific TypeScript file on a Non-TypeScript React project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I creted a `ReactJS` app with:

```
$ npx create-react-app react-app-vanilla
```

which contains these files:

```
/.gitignore
/README.md
/package.json
/public/favicon.ico
/public/index.html
/public/logo192.png
/public/logo512.png
/public/manifest.json
/public/robots.txt
/src/App.css
/src/App.js
/src/App.test.js
/src/index.css
/src/index.js
/src/logo.svg
/src/reportWebVitals.js
/src/setupTests.js
/yarn.lock
```

On file: `src/App.js` I want to use a `Greeter` helper class which I have created with `TypeScript`.

**/typescript/Greeter/Greeter.ts**

```
class Greeter {

  private greeting: string;

  constructor(message: string) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }

  greet() {
    return `Hello, ${this.greeting}`;
  }
}

export = (message: string) => new Greeter(message);
```

For now, what I'm doing (as a workaround) is running the following command manually:

```
$ npx tsc --project typescript/Greeter/tsconfig.json
```

which compiles the following file:

**/src/assets/js/utils/Greeter.js**

```
class Greeter {
    constructor(message) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return `Hello, ${this.greeting}`;
    }
}
module.exports = (message) => new Greeter(message);
```

Then I can use it on the following file:

**/src/App.js**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import greeter from './assets/js/utils/Greeter';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          {greeter('Have a Wonderful Day!').greet()}
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This file is necessary for the command above to work:

**/typescript/Greeter/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es2016", "dom"],
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": true,
    "outDir": "../../src/assets/js/utils",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "ES2017"
  },
  "files": [
    "./Greeter.ts"
  ]
}
```

**/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-app-vanilla",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

**My Goal is:**

Don't need to run that command manually in order to compile the resulting file when I update the `TypeScript` file.

We could compile the resulting file either:

- at the moment of running: `$ npm start`
- at the moment of running: `$ npm start` and when the `TypeScript` file gets updated

Do you have any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a new script to your package.json
`"compile": "tsc --project typescript/Greeter/tsconfig.json"`
and then combine these 2 commands in your `$ npm start`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run compile && react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run compile && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "compile": "tsc --project typescript/Greeter/tsconfig.json"
  },
```